# Feature request for "reopen votes" queue: Can it display the reasons for close votes?

Tags: feature-request, review, reopen

When I go through the "reopen votes" queue, it is useful to know why a question was closed. Knowing that, I can more quickly assess whether the problem has been fixed or not. (I still check for other issues, of course.) However, often the only reason given is the vague "Not suitable for this site This question doesn’t meet a English Language Learners Stack Exchange guideline". Here is a screenshot of what I mean:

[image]

In contrast, when the "close votes" queue displays the same general reason for closure, it also provides the more specific sub-reasons:

[image]

1. Is there some way to see the specific closure reasons in the "reopen votes" queue?
2. If not, then can the site be modified so that that information is displayed? (I understand that this may be difficult if the queue must work the same way across all SE sites, but perhaps it can be customized for each site.)

Comment: Ideally you would just look at the question as it currently is and decide whether it should be closed or open. You should not assume that the previously chosen close vote reasons were correct. I feel like it is intentional that the close reasons aren't displayed to prevent tainting your assessment with other people's opinions.

Comment: @ColleenV Oh, that's interesting--I hadn't thought that it might be intentional. I find it useful to know the close reasons, but yes I can see how it might wrongly influence the reviewer.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried opening the question itself?

I just found such a question in the Reopen queue, and when I opened the question itself by clicking on the title, I found the original close conditions there. It's not ideal, but better than nothing.

Comment: That works, and it's not too bad to do it for each question since there usually aren't many in the reopen queue. I was just wondering whether we could see it on the same page, which would be a bit more convenient.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan No doubt that would be cleaner. We'd need to know first what causes some Reopen Queue questions to display the original close reasons and others not. I'm guessing it's because there's more than one way of ending up in the Reopen Queue, but I don't know what those two paths could be.

Comment: Yeah, and the fact that the specific reasons show up in the close queue but not the reopen queue confused me. I'd expect similar behavior. (Perhaps they only show up sometimes in both? I haven't checked.)

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Found it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release/369362#369362). Seems in the Reopen Queue only, if the close reason was site-specific, then it doesn't show. Only the network-wide close reasons show.